# microsoftTeams is not defined

Tags: requirejs, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a teams app to expose a web page in a personal tab and I want to get hold of the current user. my typescript is

```
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";
...
microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
            microsoftTeams.getContext(() => {

                microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
```

fails at runtime with browser reporting the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: microsoftTeams is not defined
```

I am using requirejs to load the dependencies

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "wwwroot/js/app",
    paths: {
        knockout: '../lib/knockout/knockout-latest',
        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        bootstrap: '../lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min',
        smartwizard: '../lib/smartwizard/jquery.smartWizard.min',
        '@microsoft/teams-js': '../lib/teams/MicrosoftTeams.min'
    }
});

define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'smartwizard', '@microsoft/teams-js', 'NewSiteWizardViewModel'], function (ko, jquery, bs, wiz, teams, app) {
```

When that executes I can see the MicrosoftTeams.min.js file is loaded by the browser, but the teams parameter is always undefined and the microsoftTeams global variable is undefined as well, which is why the above code fails

do I need to do something else when loading it with requirejs?

Comment: How are you viewing the page? Standalone? As a "web" tab in Teams? As a Tab inside an app?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, it is a "personal" tab within the app
{
      "entityId": "3c06d05a-a654-439a-aad7-c4fde2a18eda",
      "name": "Request a Site",
      "contentUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&theme={theme}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }

Comment: @David, Code looks good. This error pops up when you you are running your application (which uses teams components) outside teams in browser..

Comment: I get the error when running in the teams app as well, I have a try catch around that code

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right. The problem is that MS teams lib is AMD compatible but it is defining itself as `microsoftTeams`. So what you need to do is to amend the ID in the config.paths and it will work as expected:

```js
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "wwwroot/js/app",
    paths: {
        knockout: '../lib/knockout/knockout-latest',
        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        bootstrap: '../lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min',
        smartwizard: '../lib/smartwizard/jquery.smartWizard.min',
        'microsoftTeams': '../lib/teams/MicrosoftTeams.min'
    }
});

define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'smartwizard', 'microsoftTeams', 'NewSiteWizardViewModel'], function (ko, jquery, bs, wiz, teams, app) {
```

Comment: if I do that then I get 2 script errors
"require.js:1961 GET http://localhost:50456/wwwroot/js/app/@microsoft/teams-js.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" and

"require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "@microsoft/teams-js", needed by: AppPageViewModel".

Interestingly the MicrosoftTeams.min file is loaded with the new name, but requirejs is not happy as it is looking for @microsoft/teams-js because of the import statement in the TS file I presume

Comment: You are right, you have to amend all the modules to use the proper ID of ms teams module. There is also another way, you can mapping in the RequireJS, but not sure whether it will work here :)

Comment: what do you mean by "you have to amend all the modules to use the proper ID of ms teams module"?

Comment: @David please look for definitions of modules which do have `@microsoft/teams-js` as dependency and amend it `microsoftTeams`, this should help